# jfree chart not loading

Tags: java, swing, user-interface, jfreechart

Hi guys

i have an assignment due where i have to make a bar chart. I have followed a tutorial on youtube. Everything seems to be compiling, but i don't know why the graph will not appear along with my GUI. This is the code:

```
public class NewjFrame extends javax.swing.JFrame {private JButton jButton1; 
public static void main(String[] args) {
    SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
        public void run() {
            NewJFrame inst = new NewJFrame();
            inst.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
            inst.setVisible(true);
        }
    });
}

public NewJFrame() {
    super();
    initGUI();
}

private void initGUI() {
    try {
        setDefaultCloseOperation(WindowConstants.DISPOSE_ON_CLOSE);
        getContentPane().setLayout(null);
        {
            jButton1 = new JButton();
            getContentPane().add(jButton1);
            jButton1.setText("jButton1");
            jButton1.setBounds(90, 19, 151, 28);
        }
        pack();
        setSize(400, 300);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        //add your error handling code here
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
private void jButton1ActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt){
    // create a dataset...
    // Create a simple Bar chart
     DefaultCategoryDataset dataset = new DefaultCategoryDataset();
     dataset.setValue(6, "Profit", "Jane");
     dataset.setValue(7, "Profit", "Tom");
     dataset.setValue(8, "Profit", "Jill");
     dataset.setValue(5, "Profit", "John");
     dataset.setValue(12, "Profit", "Fred");
     JFreeChart chart = ChartFactory.createBarChart("Comparison between Salesman", 
     "Salesman", "Profit", dataset, PlotOrientation.VERTICAL, false, true, false);
     CategoryPlot p = chart.getCategoryPlot();
     p.setRangeGridlinePaint(Color.red);
     ChartFrame frame = new ChartFrame("Bar Chart", chart);
     frame.setVisible(true);
     frame.setSize(400,350);
}
}
```

PS I am new to java so please go easy on me

Answer (score 1):

You need to add an ActionListener to `jButton1`

```
jButton1.addActionListener(new java.awt.event.ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
                jButton1ActionPerformed(evt);
            }
        });
```

You can add that inside `initGui()` just after instantiating `jButton1`.

Comment: hi thanks dave for your help, i have tried putting the actionListener in but the graph still does not nor does the swing application load

Comment: Do you get any errors when clicking the button? Do you already have `jCommon` in your classpath?